# Pseudofunctor correspondence for fibered opfibrations?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

Let $\mathcal D$ be a category. A familiar bit of category theory says that Grothendieck fibrations $\mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ are equivalent to pseudofunctors $F: \mathcal D^\mathrm{op} \to \mathsf{Cat}$.

Let's say that a *$\mathcal D$-fibered Grothendieck opfibration* is a functor $\mathcal B \to \mathcal C$ satsifying the following conditions:

1. The composite $\mathcal B \to \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ is a Grothendieck fibration.
2. $\mathcal B \to \mathcal C$ preserves $\mathcal D$-cartesian morphisms.
3. For every $D \in \mathcal D$, the fiber functor $\mathcal B_D \to \mathcal C_D$ is a Grothendieck opfibration.
4. For every $f: D' \to D$ in $\mathcal D$ and $\mathcal B_D$-cocartesian morphism $g: X \to Y$ in $\mathcal C_D$, the reindexed morphism $f^\ast(g): f^\ast(X) \to f^\ast(Y)$ in $\mathcal C_{D'}$ is $\mathcal B_{D'}$-cocartesian.

**Questions:**

(0. Is there a more standard name for $\mathcal D$-fibered Grothendieck opfibrations?)

1. What is the analog of the fibration - pseudofunctor correspondence in this setting?

For Question 1, the idea is that if $\mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ is a Grothendieck fibration, then a $\mathcal D$-fibered Grothendieck opfibration $\mathcal B \to \mathcal C$ should straighten to assign to every $D \in \mathcal D$ a pseudofunctor $G_D: \mathcal C_D \to \mathsf{Cat}$ which is "suitably functorial in $D$". But I'm wondering if somebody has written up the details.

Comment: I would guess that this falls under the heading of "indexed category theory", which I dabbled in only for a short while. I would guess this is something like an "indexed opfibration"?

Comment: If you add the additional condition that B—>C preserves Cartesian morphisms then this has been studied-see, for example, Jay Shah’s thesis on indexed colimits (you have to put opposites everywhere though- their convention is to be cocartesian over the base). In this case, if you take ‘vertical opposites’ of B and C over D to get B’ —>C’ cartesian. The straightening of this to a functor (C’)^{op}—>Cat is what you’re after I think.

Comment: (By vertical opposite I mean the construction explained in Barwick-Glasman-Nardin: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2165.pdf. Also, since you op twice in the end, the category (C’)^{op} is their C^{\vee}.)

Comment: @DylanWilson I think with that extra condition what you have is an internal opfibration in the 2-category of fibrations over $D$, right?

Comment: @DylanWilson Wow, I definitely should add that condition. I'm thinking there should be some description not involving the vertical opposite, but I suppose that's a good way to think about it.

Comment: @MikeShulman I suppose that must be what it is!

Comment: I mean, the *end* description doesn't involve the vertical opposite: C^{\vee} has objects those of C and morphisms are spans x<-- u-->y where u-->x is D-cartesian and u-->y covers the identity. The resulting pseudofunctor C^{\vee}--->Cat looks like: take an object x in C to the fiber B_x; if you have a map x-->x' over an identity in D, you get the pushforward expected B_x-->B_{x'}. On the other hand, fix e-->d in D, then you get C_d-->C_e, and what C^{\vee} is doing for you is providing a natural transformation from C_d-->Cat to the composite C_d-->C_e-->Cat.

Comment: (that's the "extra naturality" you allude to)